# Why does Dir.glob return an empty array in a Rails app template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, glob

I am implementing a custom [Rails app template](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) with a `.remove` file that lists glob-style patterns of files (e.g. `app/**/*.erb`) to be removed after `bundle install` finishes:

```
removals = File.readlines('/path/to/.remove')
cwd = Dir.getwd

after_bundle do
  # Process removals
  removals.each do |pattern|

    puts 'glob:'+cwd+'/'+pattern           # glob:/Users/acobster/starfruit/app/**/*.erb
    puts Dir.glob(cwd+'/'+pattern).count   # 0
    puts `tree #{cwd}/app`                 # all files in the app tree, 
                                           # including several .erb files

    Dir.glob(cwd+'/'+pattern).each do |filepath|
      puts "        removing #{filepath}"
      remove_file(filepath)
    end
  end
end
```

According to the debug code (see comments above), the files I want to delete (in this case all .erb files under the app/ tree) are there in the tree, but the equivalent of `Dir.glob('/Users/acobster/starfruit/app/**/*.erb')` is returning an empty array.

Weirder yet, when I run `Dir.glob('/Users/acobster/starfruit/app/**/*.erb')` from `irb`, it correctly returns the array with the three .erb files present.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just forgetting to strip off newlines from the glob patterns. I changed the first line to

```
removals = File.readlines('/path/to/.remove').map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)
```